# Set Session Timeout on Front End of site

Tags: sessions, cookies

I'm currently working on a site with a small members only section. My client would like to limit session length to 15 minutes. The time limit is for the front end of the site NOT the cp.

Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Stay Up Forever](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stay-up-forever)

It call "Forever", but based on code you can setup any session timeout in extension settings (for cpanel or/and user)

Comment: sad that EL removed user_session_ttl config variable starting from v. 2.8.0

Comment: just tested - doesn't really work :(